# How do I remove spacing between sentences or paragraphs within a cell in MS Word Table?

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting, start-menu

I am working in a document that uses a table with 2 columns.  For some reason there is a big gap in between one of my sentences. How can I get rid of this?  This is the image of the right column with wrap text.
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to look at here, but I would first start with checking to see if there is a paragraph break(s) after the first text block (between "the" and "packets".

In Word 2010, the paragraph mark can be toggled on/off from the Home tab's paragraph group.[image: photo of paragraph marker on toolbar]